# How to get JSON array data in android with Retrofit

Tags: android, arrays, json, retrofit2, gson

I'm trying to get following data in retrofit but I'm unable to get that.

```
{

"market_cap": [
    [
        1504664370000,  // unix time (milliseconds)
        74300994770     // market cap
    ],
    [
        1504750775000,
        74594182198
    ]
],
"price" : [
    [
        1504750775000,
        4507.45      <--- I want this data
    ],
    [
        1504839280000,
        4599.26      <--- I want this data
    ]
],
"volume": [
    [
        1504750775000,  
        2095800000   
    ],
    [
        1504839280000,
        1752760000
    ]
]
}
```

I only want the data in the price that I mentioned. Can someone please guide me how can I get this. I have already implemented Dailymotion JSON etc data successfully and to some extent know how to use retrofit.

But I'm facing the problem with this JSON structured data. How I make models so I can get the only price data. Thanks

Comment: post your logs.

Comment: use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ for conversion

Comment: your  json is not valid check it.

Comment: you can also use RoboPOJOGenerator plugin in android studio. See: https://github.com/robohorse/RoboPOJOGenerator for details.

Comment: jsonschema2pojo worked great. Now I'm successfully receiving only price data with retrofit. Thanks to @SabidHabib Great.